# 4-variable Karnaugh map

Tags: karnaugh-map

[image]

I would like to ask if I grouped this Karnaugh map correctly and if the equation is correct.

I'm not really sure if it's right so if it's not, how can I correctly group this? And please let me know what is wrong.

Comment: Your function isn't fully simplified because you didn't find the EPIs (essential prime implicants) correctly.  [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kgzo6nOoMxA) video explains what EPIs are.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I want to make it clear that (ABC)' is not equal to A'B'C', but you have taken so in your K-map, so check out your K-map again. Now for given K-map you have made some redundant pairs, that should not exist. You can are missing the fact that A'BC'D' is occurring in two pairs (yellow and green), which can be avoided by pairing A'B'C'D; and A'B'CD'. This should help you figure out how exactly you can reduce number of pairs.

Let me know if it makes sense to you

Thanks

Comment: We avoid giving out solutions to homework questions here. It is better to just give the OP some hints or suggestions and let them find the solution themselves.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind. For now can you please remove your downvote ?

Comment: I also add my encouragement to @Elliot to remove the downvote. I don't want to sour your own chances for a healthy relationship with Elliot. You have every right to develop your own. But I also have to admit this is one key facet of his modus operandi, too. So just be honest and true to yourself and let things play out from there. I'll add my +1 to counter this particular case. You are just trying to help out.

Comment: At this point in time the site does not allow me to remove my downvote unless you edit the answer. Do you want to try changing your answer so that it gives the OP some suggestions without actually giving the final answer?

Comment: Thank you, edited my answer